# How to know the url of opener in cross domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have two pages, having different domains.

I want to know the url of opener page, from the child page. But I am unable to do it via opener.location.

Eg.

**Page1.html:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
var handle = window.open("somedomain/Page2.html");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
alert(opener.location) //this is not working.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use #hash to pass opener url.

Page1.html

`var handle =window.open("somedomain/Page2.html#opener="+encodeURI(window.location.url));`

Page2.html

`var opener = decodeURI(window.location.hash.indexOf("=")[1]);`

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass `window.opener.location` otherwise your app won't know your `opener` object

Comment: The browser will search `window.` for any global variable.